# approach to an element that is not loaded with the DOM

Tags: jquery, dom

I have an image that I'm attaching sound to every time is displayed on the screen.

My problem is that the image is not loaded with the page DOM, she is inside a DIV that the user need to click to see the content of the div.

How can I manage a jQuery code that will check if the picture is been displayed after the DOM is loaded,

the code for playing sound:

```
  $('img#alertSound').load(function(){
    $('#imgLoadedSound').get(0).play();
  });
```

Code for the image:

```
     <div class='bell_img'><img id='alertSound' class='bell' src='bell.png'/>
```

Code for the sound:

```
     <audio id="imgLoadedSound" src="bell.mp3"></audio>
```

Comment: Post your current code. It'll make debugging it much easier.

Comment: do u want to load the image only when user click the div ?

Comment: Is there only one such img on the page, or many?

Answer (score 0):

Run the code for playing sound inside the function that appends the `<img>` tag to the `.bell_img` DIV. If you post that code, we can be more specific.